When you should use @apply in tailwind (and SCSS)
I've read that you should avoid using @apply with tailwind as much as you can. But it seems like this approach will not only make your html unbearable but it will bloat your CSS file as well. And I want to have a discussion about this, cause it seems like a reasonable combination of tailwind and SCSS will save you a lot of CSS file size.

Let's say I have a fancy button with sliding animation on hover. It requires a lot of styling for the pseudo elements as well as for the inner child element. So using just tailwind utility classes it would be hell
<button class="
    py-3 
    px-6
    inline-block
    relative
    no-underline
    overflow-hidden
    cursor-pointer
    z-0
    select-none
    rounded-none
    before:block
    before:absolute
    before:w-full
    before:content-['']
    before:inset-y-0
    before:right-0
    before:z-1
    before:translate-x-neg-full
    after:block
    after:absolute
    after:w-full
    after:content-['']
    after:inset-y-0
    after:right-0
    after:z-0
    after:translate-x-pos-full
    after:transition-transform
    after:duration-350
    after:delay-0
    after:ease-in-out
    hover:before:translate-x-0
    hover:before:transition-transform
    hover:before:duration-350
    hover:before:ease-in-out
    hover:after:opacity-100
    hover:after:translate-x-0
    hover:after:transition-transform
    hover:after:duration-350
    hover:after:delay-360
    hover:after:ease-in-out">
        <span class="relative z-5 transition-colors duration-350 ease-in-out">test</span>
</button>

Yeah, HTML is a mess but there's a larger issue: this would create about 40 classes and more than half of them won't be used anywhere on the site. But there's more: it's quite hard to control such a large scope with PHP. I mean it's quite hard to add classes and modify them, e.g. if I want to add a variation, I will have to add a PHP array to my component with variation classes. And if there are several types of variations (e.g. color and size) I'll have to add several arrays and merge them properly.
<?php
$buttonSizeVariations = [
    'default' => 'py-3 px-6',
    'small' => 'py-1 px-2',
];
$buttonColorVariations = [
    'default' => 'bg-black text-white hover:text-black before:bg-white after:bg-white',
    'inverted' => 'bg-white text-black hover:text-white before:bg-black after:bg-black'
];

But that's not the end of it. If I want to apply these styles to some other element which is not button (let's say I want checkboxes look like buttons) I will have to copy all those classes to my checkbox labels and god help me if I want to change button default padding. I would have to search through my site all the occurances of this class sequence and mannualy change the utilities throught all the site. And even that's not the end of my struggles: if I want to apply the styles to the element I have no control over (e.g. button in JS-calendar) I would have to use apply either all those classes or create a utility .btn and apply it. But in this case it will generate all those properties inside the css selector duplicating the styles for around 40 utilities.
.calendar .button {
     @apply .btn;
}

So I decided to use a combination of scss @extend + tailwind @apply
.btn-hover {
    &::before {
        @apply translate-x-0 transition-transform duration-350 ease-in-out;
    }

    &:after {
        @apply opacity-100 translate-x-0 transition-transform duration-350 delay-360 ease-in-out;
    }
}
.btn-default {
    @apply py-3 px-6;
}

.btn-generic-no-hover {
    @extend .btn-default;
    @apply inline-block relative no-underline overflow-hidden cursor-pointer z-0 select-none rounded-none;
}
.btn-generic {
    @extend .btn-generic-no-hover;

    &::after, &::before{
        @apply block absolute w-full content-[''] inset-y-0 right-0 z-negative;
    }

    &::before {
        @apply z-1 translate-x-neg-full;
    }

    &::after {
        @apply z-0 translate-x-pos-full transition-transform duration-350 delay-0 ease-in-out;
    }

    &:hover {
        @extend .btn-hover;
    }

    & > span {
        @apply relative z-5 transition-colors duration-350 ease-in-out;
    }
}

It's truly reusable solution, I can @extend any part of the button for any element of the site without getting all the utilities copied in the HTML or all the properties copied in CSS. So I think the best approach is to use SCSS and @extend whenever your classes are getting too large, hard to control or whenever you need to reuse those styles on other elements. I really don't get why add any Tailwind static utilities if they will just duplicate the styles over and over each time you want to use them to style some other element.
